# How to disable past dates and specific dates in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to create a date picker to add date into my program. so I wanna disable past dates and specific dates in the datepicker. how can I do. I have tried something in `jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/1007`   . but not disabling past dates. any help?

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/1007/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling past dates, use minDate

```
$('input').datepicker({
    minDate: +1 //enable from tomorrow and on, change to 0 if you want dates from today and on enabled
    });
```

Have a look at the jQuery UI datepicker API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/
It's quite extensive and opens many doors for you :)

Here's a fiddle using your example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CxNNh/1009/

Comment: Woow!!! It's working!!! Thanks a lot entiendoNull.